# Stopping an specify Apache instance

Tags: apache-2.2, solaris

I have two Apache instances setup in my server (Solaris 10):

**Instance 1**: /etc/apache2

**Instance 2**: /etc/apache2-instance2

To start the **instance 1**, I execute the following command:

/usr/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf

And **instance 2**:

```
/usr/apache2/bin/apachectl -f /etc/apache2-instance2/httpd.conf
```

Both instances run perfectly, however the problem comes when I want to stop the instances. I have not been able to find a parameter to indicate what instance I want to stop. if I execute this command:

```
/usr/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop
```

It will stop always the Instance 1 (the default one).

The only solution that I could find to stop the instance 2 was to do this:

```
kill -TERM 'cat /var/run/apache2-instance2/httpd.pid'
```

Is this the only way to do it? or what is the best solution?

I remember that I did something similar in Ubuntu setting a the global variable APACHE_CONFDIR before calling apachectl

Comment: Untested: Have you tried, `/usr/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop -f /etc/apache2-instance2/httpd.conf`

Comment: Perfect, it worked.

Comment: ok, turned it into an answer then.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to tell Apache to use the config file while shutting down.

```
/usr/apache2/bin/apachectl -k stop -f /etc/apache2-instance2/httpd.conf
```

that will make it look in the correct place for the PID.